# pandas dataframe to mysql db error database flavor mysql is not supported

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table in pandas dataframe df.

```
   product_id_x    product_id_y    count       date
0   288472           288473          1     2016-11-08 04:02:07
1   288473           2933696         1     2016-11-08 04:02:07
2   288473           85694162        1     2016-11-08 04:02:07
```

i want to save this table in mysql database.

i am using MySQLdb package.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.xx.xx", user="name", passwd="pwd", db="dbname")

df.to_sql(con = conn, name = 'sample_insert', if_exists = 'append', flavor = 'mysql', index = False)
```

i used this query to put it in my db.

but i am getting error.

```
ValueError: database flavor mysql is not supported
```

my datatype is str for all the columns.

```
type(df['product_id_x'][0]) = str
type(df['product_id_y'][0]) = str
type(df['count'][0])        = str
type(df['date'][0])         = str
```

i don't want to use sqlalchemy or other packages, can anyone tell what's the error here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flavor 'mysql' is deprecated in pandas version 0.19. You have to use the engine from sqlalchemy to create the connection with the database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://USER:"+'PASSWORD'+"@localhost/DATABASE")
df.to_sql(con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

When defining your engine, you need to specify your user, password, host and database. In your specific case, this should look like:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://name:pwd@xxx.xxx.xx.xx/dbname")
```

Comment: to_sql require a positional argument of `name`

Comment: `pip install MySql-Python`
`pip install SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the option you are using for `flavor` no longer exists. A brief look at the docs confirms this:

**flavor** : *‘sqlite’, default None*

DEPRECATED: this parameter will be removed in a future version, as ‘sqlite’ is the only supported option if SQLAlchemy is not installed.